# IF Statement not working correctly

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I have an IF Statement

```
=IF(AND(O4="yes",C4<11,MIN(F4,I4,L4)>=0,MAX(F4,I4,L4)<=1),C4+F4+I4,"Green")
```

But it does not seem to working correctly. In my picture below you can see that Cell C4 is greater than 11 and the result is still green in Cell R4.

Have I missed something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

error 
[image]

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because you didn't close the `And()` part in the right place.  Do you mean `=IF(AND(O4="yes",C4<11,MIN(F4,I4,L4)>=0,MAX(F4,I4,L4)<=1)),C4+F4+I4,"Green")`

Comment: `C4<11` is false, therefore your `AND()` is false. For future reference, the "Evaluate Formula" ribbon item is useful for debugging formulae.

Comment: Your `AND()` statement currently equates to false because `MAX(F4,I4,L4)` is 5 which is not less than or equal to 1.

Comment: I think you have your `>` and `<` mixed up.

Comment: To @jsheerans point. You say "you can see that Cell C4 is greater than 11", but your formula says `C4<11`, which is "C4 is less than 11". Also, @Jordan's point that the max of `F4`,`I4`,and `L4` is `5`. `5` is not less than or equal to 1, so your AND() fails on multiple criteria. Are you getting you less than and greater than confused? Are you getting AND() and OR() confused?

Comment: @BruceWayne: Thank you taking the time to respond. but when i put your formula into practice i get an error which I have added to the original post

Comment: Simple explanation: your formula with current conditions evaluates to `False`, and you wrote that `False` outputs to `"Green"`. @BruceWayne One parenthesis too many, your formula should be `=IF(AND(O4="yes",C4<11,MIN(F4,I4,L4)>=0,MAX(F4,I4,L4)<=1),C‌​4+F4+I4,"Green")`. Now the question is would you like `True` or `False` to result in `"Green"`?

Comment: @Boris: thank you for the response. I would like `Green` to be `True` Essentially what I want is that if C4 is less than 11 and F4, I4, and L4 are less than or equal to 1 then "Green" Thank you for the help

Comment: @PhilipConnell What you described results in formula `=IF(AND(C4<11,F4<=1, I4<=1,L4<=1),"Green")`. If this for some reason evaluates to `False` the result in cell will be `False`.

Comment: C4<11 is false; MAX(F4,I4,L4) = 45; therefore, the result is false and, of course, it will turn GREEN.

Comment: Hi all. Thank you for the support. I have changed tactic. I have am now trying to work out a SUMIFS formula perhaps you can help with that. What I want the formula to do is if C4 <= 11 and F4<=1 and I4 <= 1 and L4 <=1 then give the total in R 4 can you assist with this? This what i have so far `SUMIFS(C4,"<=11",F4,"<=1",I4,"<=1", I4,"<=1", C4:N4)` but obviously does not work

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by formatting. Did you merge your cells? From what I see in your screenshot, each data point is taking up 3 columns. I recreated your spreadsheet without merged cells and with each data point taking up a single row/column and your formula worked perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for the help but that did not work. Or it but the merging of cells is not a problem on my end. I have am now tryong to work out a SUMIFS formula perhaps you can help with that. What i wnat the formula to do is if C4 <= 11 and F4<=1 and I4 <= 1 and L4 <=1 then give the total in R 4 can you assist with this